# why do i Exceed the website Traffic Limit

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

hey im trying to scrape data out of a website with python selenium. Although I implanted time.sleeps() I still get blocked after 2 input scraping, the website limit is a total of no more than 10 requests per second'.  i alsotried to insert time.sleep after each row but I still got blocked. what is the reason, could you pls help me?!!!

```
enter code here
def get_results(search_term):
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
# Replace YOUR-PATH-TO-CHROMEDRIVER with your chromedriver location
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)

# Getting page HTML through request
page = driver.get(url)
# Parsing content using beautifulsouptotalScrapedInfo = [] # In this list we will save all the information we scrape
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')




try:
#'puting data in search bar'
 searchInput = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#entity-full-form")[0]
 searchInput.clear()
 searchInput.send_keys(search_term)

 first_link = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#search')[0]
 first_link.click()
 driver.save_screenshot("screenshot-before-search.png")
 
 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#col-cik")))
 Ticker_link = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#col-cik')[0]
 driver.save_screenshot("screenshot-after-search.png")

 actions = ActionChains(driver)
 actions.move_to_element(Ticker_link)
#Ticker_link.click()
 Ticker_link.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
 time.sleep(10)
 driver.save_screenshot("screenshot-after-checkbox-click.png")

 tickerSymbols = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td.cik")[0].text
 
 print(tickerSymbols)
 print(search_term)
 df['cik_col_e'][i]=tickerSymbols
 df['cik_col_e_names'][i]=search_term
 driver.save_screenshot("ticker1.png")
 print(i)
except IndexError:
    ND = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h4.text-center")[0].text
    print('ND')
    print(search_term)
    df['cik_col_e'][i]='ND'
    df['cik_col_e_names'][i]=search_term
    print(i)
    time.sleep(10)
    return


dfee=dfE
dfee=dfee[1669:2362]
for names  in dfee:
    get_results(names)
    i=i+1
    df.to_excel("pythonrun_crsp_e.xlsx")
    if i>=len(dfE):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The website you are looking to scrape has security measures put in place and can **detect that you are a bot**. I would recommend installing [selenium_stealth](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-stealth/) as well as [fake_useragent](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/) so that you can scrape without being easily detected.

### Library Installation

```
pip install selenium-stealth
pip install fake-useragent
```

### Code Implementation

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
newagent = ua.random

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

stealth(driver,
        #user_agent=newagent,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )
```

### Explanation

Websites can track many characteristics of your browsing. If you want to build a scraper that is not likely to be detected, I recommend using [this test](https://bot.sannysoft.com/) to check how secure your scraper is.